# 7-digit Julian Date to Normal Calendar Date

Tags: c#, .net, date, calendar, julian-date

How do I convert a 7-digit Julian Date (`2016092`) to a regular Calendar date (`MM-DD-YYYY`)?

I was thinking of taking the last three digits and converting it to a regular date then appending the first four digits as the year but I'd have to consider leap years.

Expected output: `04-01-2016`

My current (**SQL**) code which solves the problem is

```
DECLARE @dt char(7) 
SET @dt = 2016092 

SELECT DATEADD(dd, CAST(RIGHT(@dt, 3) AS int) - 1, CAST(LEFT(@dt, 4) AS datetime))
```

How can I implement it on **C#**?

Comment: As far as I can see `04-01-2016` equals to `2457391.50000 JD` (not `2016092`), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day online calc https://www.aavso.org/jd-calculator;

Comment: Hi, I saw this code somewhere in here (sorry if I can't provide a link) :

`DECLARE @dt char(7)  
SET @dt = 2016092
SELECT DATEADD(dd, CAST(RIGHT(@dt, 3) AS int) - 1, CAST(LEFT(@dt, 4) AS datetime))`

This is basically for SQL but it outputs the one I have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *don't have* any kind of **Julian Day** (Date) format which is

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

But a kind of *custom format* which can be reconstructed from the sql provided:

```
  year * 1000 + days from 1st Jan + 1
```

So `2016092` means `year 2016` and `092 - 1 = 91`st day from the 1st of Jan (`1st of Apr`)

**Implementation:**

```
int source = 2016092;
DateTime result = new DateTime(source / 1000, 1, 1).AddDays(source % 1000 - 1);

Console.WriteLine($"{result:MM-dd-yyyy}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
04-01-2016
```